# Adding controls (trackbars, multiline textboxes and labels) to a form under different DPIs - C#

Tags: c#, .net, controls, scaling, dpi

My application loads information from a file which then creates x amount of controls on y amounts of tabpages in a form.

My problem is that when the user has a different DPI to the standard Windows 96, the controls added overlap each other. The initial controls on the form are fine.

How can I set the controls to be modified to the 96 DPI instead of whatever the users machine is running at?

If this is very difficult, is there a way to see what the users DPI is? I can then throw a warning saying that you should use 96DPI etc etc.

Thank you for any help or advise you can give me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to answer my own question I wrote this and put it in my Form load event:

```
        Graphics formGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
        if ((formGraphics.DpiX != 96) || (formGraphics.DpiY != 96))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You are attempting to run this application in an unknown DPI. This application has been designed for Normal size (96 DPI), you may experience some display issues if you continue to use your current settings. Please change your Display settings back to normal size through your control panel to ensure you don't experience any problems. Thank you.",
            "Warning",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK,
            MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation,
            MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use Windows.Forms. You can use property `AutoScaleMode` to control how each GUI control is zoomed. There are more options you can choose, so go and try what is best for you or you can also read [this article in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229605%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to get more information on principles of zooming of controls in Windows.Forms.

Comment: Set AutoScaleMode to None. Thanks.